# unhandled exception in vc++ (msvcp100d.dll)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

I am getting a runtime exception in a file handling program in vc++.
The error is regarding dll file **msvcp100d.dll**

> Unhandled exception at 0x585a356d (msvcp100d.dll)in final.exe:
>   0xC0000005:Access violation writing location 0x00cc1a82

After debugging the program line by line, we encountered this exception on the following line :

**file.get(line,2); 
where, line is [ unsigned char * line ]**

We have gone through solutions posted on various websites.
One solution suggested was to include the dll file and place it in the debug folder of the project .
We did try this but still the problem persists.

Please help.

Comment: `After debugging the program line by line, `  Debugging doesn't just mean running the program until you see the exception.  You then look at the code and see why the problem occurs.  Your "solutions" that you said you tried is a far step from what you should be doing, and that is simply look at the code, the call, the value of the pointers, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Place the missing dll file in your System32 folder. I hope this may resolve the issue.
Step1: download the specified dll.
Step2: Goto System32 directory in your computer and paste it.

Then re-compile the code.!